# How to handle tagging and releasing of grails app using jenkins freestyle job

Tags: grails, jenkins

I have a grails app and want to release it using jenkins freestyle job. I was able to build the war file. Not able to create a tag and release the app.

Comment: Just use jenkins to fire off scripts after the grails war command is complete to finish off your development lifecycle. I do this with groovy scripts (which run ant/mvn tasks) to package the war with a release number, publish to a remote repository, tag CVS source with the same release number. I prefer the approach of deliverable scripts (i.e. in the same CVS source project as my grails app) over Jenkins configuration as it's more portable and auditable, plus you as developer have more control.

Comment: Thanks. Can you provide some links where i can see examples.